# Which languages defined in babel repeat hyphen at start of line after hyphenation?

Tags: typography, babel, hyphenation

Babel (v3.9k) states that:

> `\babelhyphen{repeat}` inserts a hard hyphen which is repeated at the
>   beginning of the next line, as done in languages like Polish, Portuguese and
>   Spanish.

I checked the definition of these languages and only Spanish has a shortcut for a hyphen that is repeated. I know that Basque and Czech have this feature with something similar to `\discretionary{-}{\char\hyphenchar\the\font}{-}\nobreak\hskip\z@}`.

- Does any other language use this feature?
- Is there any other language that has the tradition/rule to repeat the hyphen?

Comment: I don't know where _Czech_ language has this feature: I am Czech and I have never seen anybody committing such a crime.

Comment: @tohecz see last paragraph at http://prirucka.ujc.cas.cz/en/?ref=165&id=164 but I haven't seen that used in practice either

Comment: @michal.h21 That's a very unusual thing to me. I'll surely consult the institute further!

Comment: @tohecz I am totally ignorant about the Czech language :-). But `babel`  has `\discretionary{-}{\char\hyphenchar\the\font}{-}\nobreak\hskip\z@` The 3 argument of `\discretionary` is the element in the next line after the splinting of the word.

Comment: @zunbeltz And I've never ever seen anyone using it, that's my point ;)

Comment: @zunbeltz The third argument of `\discretionary` is what appears in the case of not breaking the line here. The element in the next line after splitting is the second argument.

Comment: Also repeating the hyphen on the next line after splitting the word on hyphen is logically right thing to do because then you can unambiguously reconstruct the original word.

Comment: @user87690 This is my thought also, but it seems that is not something that is widely used.